# Domain Name Pointer

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, domain-name, bluehost

i am new to web apps.

we have a domain name registered for our company and also
we have a site that is built in php and is hosted on Bluehost and live on that domain on Bluehost server.
eg. www.mybpocompany.com

BUt now we have recreated that company site in ASP.Net and placed it on a static IP in our office
192.168.*.***/ Newsite.aspx

Now I want that when our domain is requested new design is opened that is placed on our static IP.

How to route this.

pardon if the question is very basic :)

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Change the DNS zone file on bluehost to point to the new IP.